# Vue.js "Watch" not firing on simple boolean value change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

The "Watch" event isn't firing in a Vuex Store.  This is pretty basic. It's no more complicated than the example in the help. Does Watch not work in a store?

(All the answers I could find were regarding Angular.)

-Thanks

in store.js

```
state: {
    warningSwitch : false,
}

(...)

watch: {
    warningSwitch: function (newState, oldState) {
        /* console.log(" Triggered "); */
        if(newState){
            this.showWarningNotice({title: "Oops", text:"Connection Lost"});
            return;
        } else {
            this.showInfoNotice({title: "Whew...", text:"Connected"});
        }
    }
},

(...)
mutations: {
    setWarningOn(state) {
        state.warningSwitchCounter++;
        state.warningSwitch = true;
    },
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you have a watch in some component or are you trying to add a watch to the Vuex (because that's not possible)?

Comment: `watch` works in a Vue instance or a Vue component, but not in Vuex

Comment: Thanks guys. That's the answer I was looking for.  -Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "watch" in a store, as Bert alluded to in the comments.

There are two different approaches that you can take to simulate this behavior, depending on your needs and your architecture.

One, you can watch the store's getters in your component and respond to it there:

```
watch: {
    `$store.getters.warningSwitch`: function (newState, oldState) {
        /* console.log(" Triggered "); */
        if(newState){
            this.showWarningNotice({title: "Oops", text:"Connection Lost"});
            return;
        } else {
            this.showInfoNotice({title: "Whew...", text:"Connected"});
        }
    }
},
```

Two, you can actually dispatch additional behavior in the action of the store:

```
actions: {
    setWarningOn: function(context, newState) {
        // broadcast event here or commit another mutation   
    }
}
```

Comment: @CurtDoolittle I apologize if I inferred something from your post that doesn't represent your current understanding.  I've updated my answer to very directly answer your question and offer the alternatives.

Comment: cool man. np. ;)  My real job is philosophy, and I just automatically respond a bit over the top sometimes.  -cheers. ;)